# RewriteRule URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am having problems the .htaccess file using the RewriteRule. this is how my directory is right now **example.com/pages/contact.php** I want my directory to look like this **example.com/contact/** Is there a way using the rewriterule to get hide the **.php** and the sub directory **/pages/**

This is the code i have right now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^contact/$ /pages/contact.php [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Looks like your rule already does what you want.

Comment: @user2871584: What is it that is not working for you?

Comment: @anubhava To hide the .php it works but to change /pages/contact/ to /contact/ it doesnt work.

Comment: It will only work for one but i have multiple pages that way that i want to change. How do i do that? @anubhava

Comment: ok, Can you post some examples of those page names that you want to handle with these rules?